# Is map-reduce framework designed to implement commutative functions?

Tags: hadoop

I have come accross a book on hadoop. I saw this question in one of the excercises, " Is map-reduce framework designed to implement commutative functions?". Does anybody has an answer and explaination to this question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes.
MapReduce framework only guarantees that all the map tasks are finished before the reduce tasks begin, the order of each record's processing can by no means be specified. So, if the processing order matters, the result may not be constant.